# Search-box not working - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am customizing the header of this website http://onsoygolfklubb.dahlsdata-test.com/

I have added a search-box which isn't working. I think it has something to do with that something is overlapping it, because if i put it out of the header, then it works.

I tried it with a `z-index: 9999;` but this did'nt work.

Is there another way to get it work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please replace below css and it works.

```
.menu_rlinks7 { float: right; text-align: left; }
```

replace to

```
.menu_rlinks7 { float: right; text-align: left; z-index: 99999; position: relative; }
```

**z-index only work if you add position.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display:block` to **search div** like below:

```
.menu_rlinks7 {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
```

So it will work. You menu is culprit for that issue.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this did not work, I'm afraid. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I can't see your changes on the link that you gave in your question.

Comment: I did put it in now. Tried it in the inspector before.

Comment: Sorry but still not reflecting when I try.